# how to assign the body of openxml

Tags: c#, openxml, innertext

I have replaced some text of docx using my c# program and I want to assign the body of document with same style as the original document. I am having hard time doing this. How can I assign the inner text. What i want to do is body.InnerText = result and open the document and see my changes.Currently When I do this no change is made to the doc. Please help!

```
  using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path_dest, true))
            {

                var main = document.MainDocumentPart;
                var body = main.Document.Body;
                var XDoc = document.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

                string innertext = body.InnerText;
                string innerXml = body.InnerXml;
                // richTextBox1.Text = innertext;



                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(innertext, regex.ToString());

                foreach (Match m in matches)

                {
                    if (m.Success)
                    {

                      //  MessageBox.Show(m.Value.ToString());
                    }

                }

              string result =   Regex.Replace(innertext, regex.ToString(), replace_text);



                Body NEWbody = body;

                Paragraph para = NEWbody.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.AppendChild(new Text(result));
                NEWbody.InnerXml = innerXml;

                main.Document.RemoveChild<Body>(body);
                main.Document.AppendChild<Body>(NEWbody);

                ///  NEWbody.InnerText = result;



                document.Save();
                document.Close();
```

Updated attempt: the new result is that format is all lost and it comes out at as a really big paragraph

```
  using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path_dest, true))
            {

                var main = document.MainDocumentPart;
                var body = main.Document.Body;
                var XDoc = document.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

                string innertext = body.InnerText;
                string innerXml = body.InnerXml;
                // richTextBox1.Text = innertext;



                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(innertext, regex.ToString());

                foreach (Match m in matches)

                {
                    if (m.Success)
                    {

                      //  MessageBox.Show(m.Value.ToString());
                    }

                }

            string result =   Regex.Replace(innertext, regex.ToString(), replace_text);

              string resultmod = Regex.Replace(innerXml, regex.ToString(), replace_text);

          ///     main.Document.Body.InnerXml = resultmod;



              Body NEWbody = new Body();
         //  NEWbody.InnerXml = resultmod;
              Paragraph para = NEWbody.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
              Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
              run.AppendChild(new Text(result));




                 main.Document.RemoveAllChildren();




              main.Document.RemoveAllChildren<Body>();
               main.Document.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
            main.Document.AppendChild<Body>(NEWbody);

                //  NEWbody.InnerText = result;

                document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                richTextBox1.Text = main.Document.Body.InnerXml;
                document.Close();
```

My attempt using power tools for openxml. I used the TextReplacer but that doesn't allow for use of regular expressions. I wasn't able to get OpenXmlRegex to work

```
 using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wfile, true))
                {

                    //attempt using TextReplacer 
                   TextReplacer.SearchAndReplace(doc, regex1.ToString(), replace_text1, false);
                   // MessageBox.Show(doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText);
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

                    //attempt using OpenXmlRegex
                    var XDoc = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

         //tried on one paragraph that didnt work either           // IEnumerable<XElement> content = XDoc.Descendants(W.p).Take(1);


                   IEnumerable<XElement> content = XDoc.Descendants(W.Body);

                    OpenXmlPowerTools.OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, regex, replace_text, null);






                }
```

Comment: @Eric White Please help with this novice problem

Comment: Issue resolved thanks to @Eric White